# Spring boot with docker build mvn spring-boot:build-image with jvm parametes

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I am trying build docker image for my spring boot docker using the command

```
mvn spring-boot:build-image
```

And below is my docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.3'
services:
    spring-boot-container:
        ports:
            - '7000:7000'
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=${environment}
            - JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=${JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD}
            - cloud_config_uri=${cloud_config_uri}
            - "JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888"   
        image: 'artifactory.cloud.health.com/docker-all/spring_boot_app:latest'
        restart: always
        container_name: spring_boot_app
```

But my spring boot app is not coming up with proper profiles and not picking java _opts.

Basically in old approach i create dockerfile, then i give `ENTRYPOINT` where i pass `-Dspring.active.profiles`.

But since we using `mvn spring-boot:build-image` i dont know how we pass those entrypoint variables.

Comment: Why not simply pass `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev`? Why this complex resolution? Also unless you do something with `JAVA_OPTS` it won't do a thing. Also shouldn't the `"` be removed?

Comment: where and how do we pass it in compose file, and its not just about spring profiles,  i have many arg parameter to pass.

Comment: You currently have 2 competing properties for the profiles only one will remain. I suspect the one from the command line nor will it use JAVA_OPTS if that isn't present in the first place. Also what is that `${environment}` if that can't be resolved it will error out.

Comment: For profiles yeah i agree, but none of it is working.  i just gave to show that i tried in both the places.   ${environment} is env i am passign using export command.

Comment: Well ofcourse that won't work. The `${environment}` will be resolved inside the docker container **not** on your local system.

Comment: And environment variables need to be uppercase with a _ seperator. So `cloud_config_uri` won't work/resolve and it should be `SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI` instead as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally resolved, its syntax issue. The below way of writing environment works!

```
        environment:
            - JAVA_OPTS=
                -Dspring.profiles.active=${environment}
                -Dspring.cloud.config.enabled=true
                -Dspring.cloud.config.uri=${cloud_config_uri}
                -Djasypt.encryptor.password=${JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD}
```